# sending to individual socketid (private message) doesnt work in socketIO

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Im trying to build a small chat application where i could send private message(not broadcasting to all). to a selected socketid. I went through the documentation of SockeIO and could find a solution which works. The application works well because i tested it using a broadcasting event an all connected sockets received the emitted message. How to achieve personal messaging?.

This is the code i have tried.

```
socket.to(sockets[data.receiver]).emit('receive',data.message);
```

Where i have used the **socket.to().emit('hey', 'I just met you');** example given in socketio docs and sockets[data.receiver] gives out the socket.id of the person which the message to be sent.

Comment: just select the socket for the client that you want to send data to and make a normal socket.emit

Comment: more example code helps too

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa Thats what i have tried but its not working and what do you mean by a normal socket.emit? i didn't find any method other than this, to send data to selected socket.

Comment: save the full socket on a object, and try to call the emit from that socket later

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like the following:

```
class Connection {
        constructor(name, socket) {
                this.name = name;
                this.socket = socket;
        }
}

let connections = [];

socket.on('connection', (socket) => {
        // Get a name for the user/connection
        // ...
        // let name = getUsername(socket);

        connections.push(new Connection(name, socket));
});

let sendToName = (name, message) => {
        for(let i = 0, len = connections.length; i < len; i++) {
                if(connections[i].name === name) {
                        connections[i].socket.emit('message', message);
                        break;
                }
        }
};
```

Of course, you could use something other than name... but you get the idea.

Comment: I've tried something similar i saved the socket.id with the name of the user and use it to emit to user but the  **socket.to(socket.id).emit('chat', 'message');** function isnt working. And i tried your code and its not working

Comment: you don't need socket.to when you're dealing with the specific socket to that user/connection... only socket.emit('chat', message).  The code I posted is not a complete example, just some boilerplate to give an idea of a better direction.